# Add printer to system using Powershell within VBA?

Tags: vba, powershell

I can make it work with a batch file using:

```
powershell.exe "Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006"
```

But if I try to run the bat file above with VBA, it does not add the printer:

```
Shell ("c:\Fraktsedlar\HELPS006.bat")
```

If I run powershell directly from VBA, none of these works either:

```
Shell ("powershell.exe -Command " & Chr(34) & "Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006" & Chr(34))

Shell ("powershell.exe -Command {" & Chr(34) & "Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006" & Chr(34) & "}")

Shell ("powershell.exe -Command " & Chr(34) & "{Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006}" & Chr(34))
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any output? Errors?

Comment: No, as far as I can see they just flicker my the screen. Usually when I get an error I see something red before it closes. Can I make it pause somehow?

Comment: Just checking you're just trying to add a printer, and not add as default? (only mentioned in subject but not in question)

Comment: True, that is correct my title is wrong. I'm actually trying to make it default, but since I can't add it that is the first problem. But making it default works, if I just can install it

Comment: @Andreas, you could add `-NoExit` switch to powershell.exe or just add pause, like so: `{Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006; pause}` to see if there is output.

Comment: I get the following error: *Cannot load PSReadline module.  Console is running without PSReadline.

Add-printer : The driver needed to connect to this print share cannot be retrieved from the server and must be manually

installed.

At line:1 char:5

+ & { Add-printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006 }

+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Add-Printer], CimException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070bcb,Add-Printer* with your first code

Comment: @Andreas, are you trying from an elevated prompt?

Comment: Not sure what elevated prompt is... :-/ but the answer CatCat wrote works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If powershell can do it so VBA.

From Help

http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe This contains some libraries for system admin. You can use all of Windows Scripting Host features except for the root `wscript` object (used by a script to communicate with the host). 1000 times as much admin/info can be used with **WMI** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393262(v=vs.85).aspx.

WSH has a second add printer function. Look at that one.

Adds a Windows-based printer connection to your computer system.

```
object.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strPrinterPath
```

**object**

`WshNetwork` object.

**strPrinterPath**

String value indicating the path to the printer connection.

**Example**

The following code uses the `AddWindowsPrinterConnection` method to connect a network printer to a Windows NT/2000 computer system.

```
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
PrinterPath = "\\printserv\DefaultPrinter"
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath
```

Comment: That was a vbscript specific `CreateObject` (because it came from Windows Scripting Help - JScript/VBScript/Windows Script Host). Just use the normal VBA/VBScript's `CreateObject`.

Comment: If you want to know how a program does something open program in notepad and look for the API calls it makes. Then you can make the same API calls in VBA.

Comment: That was it! It just prompts me with "install driver?" And that's fine. I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Shell ("powershell.exe -Command { Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006 }")
```

Or this:

```
Shell ("powershell.exe -Command " & Chr(34) & "& { Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006 }" & Chr(34))
```

You can also try this which is what `Add-Printer` does:

```
$p = Get-WmiObject -List Win32_Printer -EnableAllPrivileges
$p.AddPrinterConnection ("\\PS02.samba.net\HELPS006")
```